# Django - South - Is There a way to view the SQL it runs?

Tags: python, database, migration, django-south

Here's what I want to do.

Develop a Django project on a development server with a development database.  Run the south migrations as necessary when I change the model.

Save the SQL from each migration, and apply those to the production server when I'm ready to deploy.

Is such a thing possible with South?  (I'd also be curious what others do to get your development database changes on production when working with Django)

Comment: Sheer curiosity: Why do you wish to make the changes manually, instead of migrating the app with South on production as well?

Comment: It's going to be pretty critical data, and honestly I don't know if I trust any package enough to have at my data.  I'd rather inspect the SQL it's going to run first to make sure it won't harm anything.  I guess I could take the system offline and backup the data before migrating.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. My experience with South has been good enough for me to have some trust that things won't go... well, south. :-) I also don't think South has any way to inspect the resulting SQL though, but I might be wrong. Adding a bounty to see if someone chimes in with a definitive answer.

Comment: When south goes wrong (it does have warts) - sometimes it is time to bring out the mysql command line, and fire through the SQL manually, then run the migration with "--fake". I hate to do so. The alternative would be to fix/patch south if I can figure out how. This then becomes a question of how much time you have...

Answer (score 50):

You can at least inspect the sql generated by doing `manage.py migrate --db-dry-run --verbosity=2`. This will not do anything to the database and will show all the sql. I would still make a backup though, better safe than sorry.

Comment: This does *not* show the SQL in South version 0.7.6. Has the behavior been changed along the way?

Comment: Ah, it doesn't show the SQL for ALTER TABLEs (South 0.7.6, PostgreSQL 9.1). Instead, it displays the message "no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry". Is this a PostgreSQL limitation?

Comment: @akaihola: MySQL appears to have the same limitation.

Comment: same message in Oracle.

Comment: I get `./manage.py: error: no such option: --db-dry-run` is this only in south?

Comment: @gollumullog  yes South only. For Django migrations there is `sqlmigrate` command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate

Answer (score 8):

```
 python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> <migration_name>
```

Comment: This won't work with south (as needed by OP) but will do the tirk if you're using new django builtin migrations.

Answer (score 3):

You could try logging the SQL queries in db.connection.queries, using a management command that calls the migrate with a dry-run option:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django import db

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Output SQL for migration'

    def handle(self, *app_labels, **options):
        # assumes DEBUG is True in settings
        db.reset_queries()

        from django.core.management import call_command
        kw = {'db-dry-run': 1,  'verbosity': 0}
        call_command('migrate', **kw)

        for query in db.connection.queries:
            print query['sql']
```

Assuming that south puts everything through the usual db interface that should work.  There will be a few extra selects in there when it queries the history table.

You'd put that in a `management/commands/print_migration_sql.py` inside your app and then run it:

```
python manage.py print_migration_sql
```

It could probably be easily extended to run this only for specific apps etc

Comment: Does anyone have a deeper knowledge if south does uses the usual db interface? to me this would be the best approach, considering too what @john-montgomery has proposed.

Comment: if you run with db-dry-run you will get some messages, `"no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry"`.

Answer (score 3):

When I need to see the SQL that South generates for debugging or verification I just add the following logging settings to my local_settings.LOGGING.loggers:

```
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
```

This is a complete example of the logging setting for South:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(name)s %(lineno)d "%(message)s"'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

This will output everything including the query that South runs to decide what migrations to run:

```
[2014-03-12 23:47:31,385] DEBUG django.db.backends 79 "(0.001) SELECT `south_migrationhistory`.`id`, `south_migrationhistory`.`app_name`, `south_migrationhistory`.`migration`, `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` FROM `south_migrationhistory` WHERE `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` ASC; args=()"
```

That and setting verbosity to 2 or 3 is usually more than enough to get a clear picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I'd either do what Lutger suggested (and maybe write a log parser to strip out *just* the SQL), or I'd run my migration against a test database with logging enabled on the test DB.

Of course, if you can run it against the test database, you're just a few steps away from validating the migration.  If it passes, run it again against production.