# relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist. Migrate does not create these tables

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth. But when I run makemigrations and migrate. The tables "social_auth-*" are not created.

My settings.py looks like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS += (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Rausnehmen wenns Probleme mit der Auth. gibt

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  # <--- enable this one. to match users per email adress
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

from sharadar.soc_auth_config import *
```

The same does work on another machine without any flaw. On this machine I receive :

```
Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, easy_thumbnailsguardian, main, myauth, sessions, social_auth
Running migrations:
    Applying myauth.0002_auto_20170220_1408... OK
```

social_auth is included here.

But on a new Computer I allways receive

```
Exception Value:    
relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist
LINE 1: ...er"."bio", "myauth_shruser"."email_verified" FROM "social_au...
```

When using google auth in my running django app

social_auth is not included when I run migrate

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, easy_thumbnails, guardian, myauth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Any help is appretiated.

Kind regards

Michael

Comment: do you have two computers with different setup?

Comment: yes i have one computer with a working setup. But I cannot get it to run on the second

Comment: Probably n your old setup python-social-auth migrations has been run after the migrations of the custom user model. I mean the sequence of migrations can matter in this case. You can try to disable python social auth in new setup, run migrations and then install it.

Comment: I have uninstalled python-social-auth. Removed it from installed apps. Recreated the database only with "my" migrations. Reinstalled social-auth and rerun makemigrations and migrate still just my apps ;-( no social_auth

Comment: do you have some custom config from sharadar.soc_auth_config import *?

Comment: just links like : SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' Keys for GOOGLE and FACEBOOK as well. Can I run makemigrations and migrate more verbosely ?

Comment: you mean something similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5897509/709897

Comment: on the machine where it is working I receive

Comment: .......
.......
Running pre-migrate handlers for application myauth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application main
Running pre-migrate handlers for application social_auth

Comment: and where it is not working I receive

Comment: Ah ... a lot of migrations are missing ... I will have a look on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to migrate to social-auth-core as described in this dokument :

[Migrating from python-social-auth to split social](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/MIGRATING_TO_SOCIAL.md)

Then all is working fine. But after this problems I am thinking about changing to all-auth.

Regards for any help

Answer (score 0):

Strange .. when entering the admin interface I receive the exception :

```
No installed app with label 'social_django'.
```

But later in the Error Report I have :

```
INSTALLED_APPS  
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     .....
     'myauth.apps.MyauthConfig',
     'main.apps.MainConfig',
     'social.apps.django_app.default']
```

pip3 search for python-social-auth gives :

```
python-social-auth (0.3.6) 
    INSTALLED: 0.3.6 (latest)
```

I dont know what is going on here.

Regards

Michael

Comment: Initially not. But to crosscheck. I also created a virtualenv and I do receive the same problem there as well. The migrations are not performed. Tables are not created.

Comment: I even created a empty new project "mysite" with one app "polls" and included python-social-auth in installed_apps there, The migrations are not performed whatever I do ?

Comment: michael@mibi:~/tmp/mysite$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
michael@mibi:~/tmp/mysite$